Do proposal outcomes measure impacts?
I'm working on a grant and I've run into this phrase:
"secondary outcomes measuring the impact...".
Here's the sentence:

The Award will fund analysis of secondary outcomes measuring the impact that DARGs have on BARD expression.


Is it that the term "secondary outcomes" serves as a label (a term of art) to name what the research is doing? 
If this is the case, then is acceptable to indicate:
"secondary outcomes measure the impact..."?

However, just thinking about the definition of outcomes, it seems that secondary outcomes are the results derived from measuring the impact.


If the secondary outcomes are the results or measurements, what is the correct way to indicate what the award funds (by the way, the "secondary outcomes" are from a different study than the award that I'm writing)?

The award will fund analysis to determine the impact the DARG approach has on GARD dysregulation and BARD expression (Secondary Outcomes for Project A).


Are you sure "measuring the impact..." is modifying "outcomes" rather than "analysis"?

It makes sense that "measuring the impact" is modifying "analysis". But I guess I'm confused about what is being analyzed. It sounds like "secondary outcomes" are being analyzed. So maybe what is meant is that the analysis of "secondary outcomes" from Project A are the new outcomes for Project B?

The outcomes of the research are the inputs to the analysis. Typically in medical research you collect a whole bunch of data more or less relevant to the study, and hope some of them have changed in a way that seems meaningful. A good study shouldn't really have lots of secondary outcomes because it should be trying to prove one thing defined in advance. But it's common to look at different measurements because some will change more quickly than others, and numerical measures may be more useful than binaries (dead/alive). You should learn more about medical research before writing proposals!

It doesn't need overthinking. It's clear that what's funded is analysis, what's analyzed is secondary outcomes, and the thing that does the "measuring" is the analysis, not the outcomes. Here are a few rewordings that might help clarify:

The Award will fund analysis of secondary outcomes. This analysis will measure the impact that...
OR
The Award will fund analysis of secondary outcomes which measures the impact that...

Or, trying to use more everyday language: The grant will pay for people to look closer at the effects of DARGs, looking beyond the primary findings to "secondary outcomes," and measuring the impact of DARGS on BARD expression.
(Note: to make sure I'm understanding it correctly, I just looked up the phrase "secondary outcome." If you're unclear too, maybe that's a good idea.)
